# Why do very small balls attached to a tiny spring propel themselves in hardly moving fluids?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, spring, molecules

I recall watching a youtube video about a ball with a spring on the idea propelling themselves through stable fluids without any assistance, even if we make sure the spring isn't moving in the beginning. It'd be a great help to get an explanation as to why this happens since I haven't been able to find the video after searching for quite a long time.
Since soap molecules also share the same shape as a ball and a spring, it may be possible that soap molecules could propel themselves as well.